# Unable to connect to AWS windows instance created using self created AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Created a new AMI (Windows 2019 based - syspreped) and then an instance using the syspreped-AMI. now after an hour when i try to get the password for the instance i get below error. i have tried with non-syspreped and syspreped AMIs same issue. Used the steps to sysprep from the following document https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2019&p=sysprep . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully create an AMI when i syspreped the EC2 using steps from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html#sysprep-gui-procedure

Previously for some reason it did not remove all the details/properties so when the AMI was created it was still using the password for the parent instance.